# Why can't Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting get the DbSet<T> returned from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, tdd

1. Project:Web Api
2. run path: open the TestExplorer and right click the item you want to test,and left click debug selected tests
3. Problem Description: I traced the sql server with sql server profiler, and the sql server received the requesting and returned the Items. but the TDD project get nothing. below is the relevant code:

---

```
// the test project test
[TestMethod]
public void GetCategoryTrees()
{
    //Arrange
    CategoryTreesController controller = new CategoryTreesController();
    //Act
    List<CategoryTree> result = controller.GetCategoryTrees();
    //Assert
    Assert.AreNotEqual(0, result.Count);
}


// the real project code
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

// GET: api/CategoryTrees
public List<CategoryTree> GetCategoryTrees()
{
    db.CategoryTrees.Load();
    return db.CategoryTrees.ToList();
}
```

when I visit api/CategoryTrees in IE explorer, I can get the Items in immediate window. and there are 14 items.
But when I ran test project in previous mentioned run path, I got nothing.
Please help me, thank you.

```
//below code was coded in immediate window under test mode
db.CategoryTrees.ToList()
Count = 0
db.CategoryTrees.Load()
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
```

// below code was coded immediate window under visit IE mode

```
 db.CategoryTrees.ToList()
Count = 14
    [0]: {Models.CategoryTree}
    [1]: {Models.CategoryTree}
    [2]: {Models.CategoryTree}
    [3]: {Models.CategoryTree}
    [4]: {Models.CategoryTree}
    [5]: {Models.CategoryTree}
    [6]: {Models.CategoryTree}
    [7]: {Models.CategoryTree}
    [8]: {Models.CategoryTree}
    [9]: {Models.CategoryTree}
    [10]: {Models.CategoryTree}
    [11]: {Models.CategoryTree}
    [12]: {Models.CategoryTree}
    [13]: {Models.CategoryTree}
```

Comment: Check app.config and make sure you have the correct connection string for the dbcontext.

Comment: @Nkosi I am sure about that, cause my database received the requesting T-sql

Answer (score 0):

- According to my discretion, I think I am on the wrong way.
  regardless of the test code run successfully or not, that is not the
  core of testability code design ,I raised my test code complexity,
  thus I will isolate the code, and make it testable.
- Thank @Nkosi for commenting this